# Explanation of numbers in haskell: Not off topic: too broad?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits

I got [a review question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/31841767/revisions) and it was a "test" to see if I was paying attention. Now I've edited the question to reflect the answer of Thomas, but I really don't think this should be a test for the review queue. I closed it as "too broad" and I still wonder if this question isn't too basic. I mean, any book on Haskell will include this data, right? And what about the language specification itself?

I've edited the question just to make sure other's don't get suckered into voting it off topic as too broad; please take a look at my edit.

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/31841767/revisions

Could we remove this particular test case from the close vote review please?

Comment: Your edit made the question clearly _too broad_,  and the only answers that probably could be expected are RTFM.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ WTF? I removed requests for more information, and *my edit* made it "too broad"??? That's just not logically possible.

Comment: I meant your edits made the question just bluntly broad now. Removing requests for more information isn't any improvement regarding that point.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Note that the *accepted* answer didn't contain any of the requested information (outside the fact that it states that `Num` is the parent type).